# Angular material 2 fab button does not gets floated it is getting scrolled with content what can be the reason for it?

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
<button md-fab></button>
```

angular  material button does not  gets sticky though I positioned it fixed. This button gets scrolled with the content. I also added a class and tried

```
.fltBtn{
    position:fixed; 
    right:30px;
    bottom:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide your html ? It might interfere with your css.

Please see my answer here [angular 2 material container fixed not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034109/angular-2-material-container-fixed-not-working/42070853?noredirect=1#comment71411523_42070853)

If you are using a sidenav, it probably comes from here.